# Office Online Server: We couldn't find the file you wanted. It's possible the file was renamed, moved or deleted

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, office-online-server

I am having a issue with my SharePoint and Office Online Server. Below is the setup

**SharePoint2016 on premise**. One server is the DB server and another is the SharePoint server

I have installed the Office Online Server on my DB server since it can't be installed on the SharePoint server.

In SharePoint I can see it tries to open the document with Excel or Word Online.. also I have the option to create a new document right on the SharePoint.

But when i try to open a document in a browser in Excel or Word Online I am getting these messages.. no idea what the issue can be

> Sorry, we're having a problem showing this workbook. Details
>
> Something is preventing us from opening the workbook. It might be
>   blocked for security reasons. Unable to Open the File Close
>
> We couldn't find the file you wanted.
>   It's possible the file was renamed, moved or deleted.

Answer (score 1):

First, the docs [specifically state](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/plan-office-online-server) that OOS is not to be installed on SQL server:

"Don't install any other server applications on the server that's running Office Online Server. This includes Exchange Server, SharePoint Server, Skype for Business Server, and SQL Server. If you have a shortage of servers, consider running Office Online Server in a virtual machine on one of the servers you have"

Second, the error is most likely due to your wopibindings. Please post the command you used to configure the OOS farm, and please post how you configured it on the SharePoint server.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82328/discussion-on-answer-by-mike2500-sharepoing-2016-and-office-online-server).

Answer (score 0):

Release the existing WOPI binding in SharePoint Management Shell and renew it with this script:

```
Remove-SPWOPIBinding -All:$true

New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName *YourOfficeOnlineServerNameHere*
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all SharePoint Server 2016 web applications use claims-based authentication. Office Online rendering and editing won’t work on SharePoint Server 2016 web applications that use classic mode authentication.

If you log on to SharePoint Server 2016 by using the System Account, you won’t be able to test the connection between SharePoint Server 2016 and Office Online Server. Log on with a different account to test the connection.

Low memory conditions can cause Office document previews to fail in Office Online.

Besides, you can remove Office Online server farm from SharePoint and recreate the Office Online server farm from SharePoint.

Here is an similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c01db59e-6f9a-430f-8152-f50691d0558e/sharepoinit-2016-and-office-online-server?forum=SP2016

Answer (score 0):

1. First try to check if the File is opening in the Office online server.
2. After integration with SharePoint, check if the SharePoint site is accessible from the office online server. (I had a similar problem that the site was not accessible on office online server as we were building a new farm and there were no DNS entries.) To fix it, add entry in hosts file for SharePoint site on office online server.